# How to set list count in growing list/table title in ui5?

Tags: sapui5

In sap.m.Table/List, I defined a title

```
            <Title
                id="lineItemsHeader"
                text="{tableView>/lineItemListTitle}"/>
```

Get count logic is in `updateFinished` function,

```
        onListUpdateFinished : function (oEvent) {
            var sTitle,
                iTotalItems = oEvent.getParameter("total"),
                oViewModel = this.getModel("tableView");

            // only update the counter if the length is final
            if (this._oTable.getBinding("items").isLengthFinal()) {
                if (iTotalItems) {
                    sTitle = this.getResourceBundle().getText("DETAIL_TABLE_HEADING_COUNT", [iTotalItems]);
                } else {
                    //Display 'Line Items' instead of 'Line items (0)'
                    sTitle = this.getResourceBundle().getText("DETAIL_TABLE_HEADING");
                }
                oViewModel.setProperty("/lineItemListTitle", sTitle);
            }
        }
```

But if I set `growing="true"`, when data is more than 20 items(default growing threshold), `this._oTable.getBinding("items").isLengthFinal()` will return `false`.

So I came up an idea, use `$count` directly to get count data.

```
                this._oModel.read("/ControlSet/$count", {
                        success: this._updateListItemCount.bind(this), 
                        error: this.errorCallback.bind(this)
                });
```

But the question came up when I try to get count of filter result, I know the call is `/ControlSet/$count?$filter=(substringof('a',name) or substringof('a',description))`, and I've already maintain a filter state:

```
            this._oListFilterState = {
                aSearch : [new Filter...]
            };
```

Did not find any clue in https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.Filter

Any suggestion? Try do fix this in an elegant/ui5 way, better not use        $.get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by :

```
            this._oListFilterState = {
                aSearch : undefined
            };

        onUpdateFinished : function () {
            this.byId("pullToRefresh").hide();

            if(this._oListFilterState.aSearch) {
                 this._oModel.read("/ControlSet/$count", {
                    filters: [this._oListFilterState.aSearch],
                    success: this._updateListItemCount.bind(this), 
                    error: this.errorCallback.bind(this)
                });
            }else {
                this._oModel.read("/ControlSet/$count", {
                    success: this._updateListItemCount.bind(this), 
                    error: this.errorCallback.bind(this)
                });
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

On update finished event you can even use the below code also

```
 updatingCount : function(oEvent){
            var tableCount = oEvent.getParameters().actual;
        }
```

> This can be used without hitting the $count service

Comment: The `actual` parameter only get the current loaded items count, but I want to get whole items count from backend. I think only backend/service will have this knowledge.